# Creating multiple ISCSI LUNs from one disk, under Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, iscsi

I have a 2.7 TB virtual disk (LSI MegaRAID controller with ten 600GB SAS drives configured in RAID10) under Linux. I am sharing this disk to a remote ESX host via ISCSI.

Unfortunately ESX will only make a 740GB VMFS partition if you present it LUN greater than 2TB. I could make a 6 disk RAID10 (which would be smaller than 2TB) but I really don't want to lose spindles (IOPS).

Is there a way to split this big RAID10 virtual disk up (for ESX) in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two [partitions | logical drives | target files] and export them as iSCSI LUNs.

Comment: # cat /etc/ietd.conf TARGET iqn:2006-03.local.sol:fast
      Lun 0 Path=/dev/sda,Type=fileio
      Lun 1 Path=/dev/sdb1,Type=fileio
      Lun 2 Path=/dev/sdb2,Type=fileio. Like so?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the config file for the Target software you're using.

Answer (score 0):

you have a few options:

- break the hardware raid from raid 10 and make a different raid(raid 6 will give you more space - ((600GB * 1024 * 1024 * 10)  - (600GB * 1024 * 1024 * 2)) / 1024 / 1024 = 4800GB)
- use it as is with two or more partitions (see @Chris S)

in any case the solution at linux level is to split the disk into partitions and export them via different ISCSI targets. if you keep one big drive you are limited to 4 primary partitions as if you have a raid6 you can export to linux different drives (sda, sdb ect) which in turn can have different partitions. To calculate this you can use n_drives * 4partitions = ISCSI targets.